# Native Base how can I get ListItem index of List dataArray?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native-base

I'm wanting to access the index of a thats being generated from with dataArray.
For example:

```
<List dataArray={this.props.groceries} renderRow={(groceryListItem, index) =>
    <ListItem>  
        <Text>{index}</Text>
    </ListItem>
    }
>
</List>
```

However, this does not work. How can I access this dynamic index?
Thanks!

Comment: Is that possible for you to use react-native `FlatList`? index is accessible in renderItem method of `FlatList`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is List is it ListView? İf it is you can get the index 3. prop

```
<ListView 
renderRow={(rowData, sectionID, index) => // you can get the index from 3.
...
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. List is a Native Base component.

Comment: Okey I got it. I am happy to help my answers for you

Comment: It is works for me too with 2.x version

Answer (score 0):

React Native [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist) has similar structure to your `List` component and it's highly recommended by react native community to use `FlatList` because of efficiency, `index` of rendered item is accessible easily. here is an simple usage for what you want:

```
render() {
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={[
        {title: "title1"},
        {title: "title2"},
        {title: "title3"},
        {title: "title4"},
        {title: "title5"},
        {title: "title6"},
        {title: "title7"},
        {title: "title8"},
      ]}
      renderItem={(item) => <Text>{item.index}</Text>}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}/>
  );
}
```

`item` parameter in `renderItem` has two important property.

1. index: index of item being rendered
2. data: the data you provided to flat list, in this sample is one of objects of array passed to `data` props of flatList, e.g. `{title: "title1"}` that I don't use this data in `renderItem` method. you can do what you want with it in your way like this: `data={this.props.groceries}`

Answer (score 0):

I am using following:

```
<List dataArray={this.props.groceries} renderItem={({item, index}) =>
    <ListItem key={index}>  
        <Text>{item}</Text>
    </ListItem>
    }
>
</List>
```